# How mysqli handles arrays with two fildes with same name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm wondering how does mysqli handles array with two (or more) fields with the same name. For example, I have a query:

```
SELECT c.*, h1.name, h2.name
FROM connections AS c 
LEFT JOIN hw AS h1 
ON c.hw1 = h1.id 
LEFT JOIN hw AS h2 
ON c.hw2 = h2.id 
WHERE h1.active = 1 
AND h2.active = 1
```

And when I do fetch_array function with MYSQLI_ASSOC I should get an array with 2 fields 'name'. Does mysqli somehow differentiate between them or does some data get lost?

I know I can use **MYSQLI_NUM** or **SELECT c.*, h1.name as name1 etc.**, but I'm curious what happens when I will do it this particular way. What are the mechanisms behind it?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what you actually get? It would have been quicker than asking here and waiting for answers.

Comment: I already did, it seems that one of the fields gets lost, however, I'm curious how it is done, is there some exception to be caught etc. Because I didn't get any errors, just one-field-smaller-then-expected array ;)

Comment: Technically, it isn't an exception, or an error, which is why it works.... MySQLi doesn't try to do anything clever, just associates each column value in turn with the column name, which is 'name'.... the fact that it already has a value from the first `name` column when it stores the value for the second `name` column simply means that it overwrites the previous with the next